# Vertically center active li in the ul

Tags: css

I want to do something like musixmatch. I want to display the active verse at the center of `ul`.

[image]

I know how to do it in javascript, but is it possible to do it with pure CSS?

```
<ul id="lyrics">
    <li>You know, everybody's been tellin' me what they think about me for the last few months</li>
    <li class="active">It's too loud</li>
    <li>Maybe it's time I tell 'em what I think about them</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
body {
    background: #252525;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}   

#lyrics {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    position: fixed;
    width: 70%;
    list-style: none;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 50vh;
    color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#lyrics .active {
    color: cornsilk;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about it:

```
#lyrics {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
position: fixed;
width: 70%;
list-style: none;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
left: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 2em;
height: 50vh;
color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

0While you are trying to change the positioning of the text in correspondence to the song, which involves the use of time, you certainly need Javascript; but if you're asking only about changing the positioning of text, then-

- wrap the `active` div around the next line
- change the value of the `top` tag to a negative pixel value/percentage

For example, if you want the next line of the song highlighted, this is the code:

```css
body {
    background: #252525;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}   

#box {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
    position: fixed;
    width: 70%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 50vh;
    color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
    position: relative;
    top: -15%;
    list-style: none;
}

#lyrics .active {
    color: cornsilk;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div id = "box">
<ul id="lyrics">
    <li>You know, everybody's been tellin' me what they think about me for the last few months</li>
    <li>It's too loud</li>
    <li class="active">Maybe it's time I tell 'em what I think about them</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

There are some changes I have made to the code. I have wrapped the `ul` around a `div` by the id `box`. I have transferred all the CSS properties of the id `lyrics` to `box` and to the `ul`, I have made its position `relative`(relates not to the main screen but to the box inside which it is) and have set a negative value to the `top` attribute, in order to move the text upwards, making the next line visible.

**Note**: I have set `-120%` based on its preview. If in case you want a full page result change it to something like `-20%` or `-15%`.

[image: Output]
I hope this is what you asked for and that it helps.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, I guess it's just better to do it with JavaScript. I was hoping to just set class to `active` in JS and it would magically center itself possibly with some scroll like effect.

Comment: @Konrad does the image describe your requirements?

Comment: yeah, I  think I will do it differently anyway to achieve similar result